# Error executing command from .NET: The supplied kernel information version is invalid

Tags: c#, .net, powershell, cmd

I'm trying to execute a command from inside a .NET process. The command works just fine in Powershell or a regular command prompt executed by the same user as used for the .NET process.

I am trying to update the RRAS SSTP cert on **Windows server 2016** with the following command:

```
netsh ras set sstp-ssl-cert name=bla.domain.foo
```

The error I'm getting is the following:
**The supplied kernel information version is invalid.**

This is the code I'm using to execute from inside a simple .NET console application. Outputting logic omitted for brevity.

```
using (var powerShellInstance = PowerShell.Create())
{
    powerShellInstance.AddScript(command);
    powerShellInstance.Invoke();
}
```

I'm using the **.NET framework 4.6.1**, I have tried adding a manifest to up the required execution rights but neither that or running as admin manually changes anything.

The application is executed by a scheduled task and if I manually add the required script as a step directly executing with cmd.exe it works like a charm. This is not very clean however, and requires me knowing the cert name when creating the task. There are a million ways I can overcome this issue but for the life of me I don't understand why it doesn't just work from .NET while all other commands I require are working fine.

Answer (score 1):

So, this is not really a PoSH specific thing natively. That error message is more general than specific to .Net use case.

This error message is not unique to what you at doing, especially most recently on Win10. This error has been reported, since the 1703 release, even just when doing things on the file system, like WDS captures, folder creation etc.

Several reasons have been postulated, permissions and the like, but all had to just come up with a workaround (permission fixes, etc.) as you have indicated the you have a million ways to address your use case.

But to get to potential root cause, you need to look deeper at the other Windows event log information, Application, Security, System and PowerShell logs from when you are doing your .Net effort.

Comment: Yea the WDS posts were the only references I found to the error. Unfortunatly all event logs remain empty and the only result I get from the powershell output is the message I posted. The Error stream remains empty... if you have any other ideas of where to look I am open to sugestions.

Comment: Hummm.  Nothing in the event logs with this error is very odd.  I'd crank up the audit levels and try again. For me to determine anything further, I'd have to spin up something to see anything further. Right now my VS2K15 is borked, not sure what did it, and now I have to manually remove all of it. Argh! reg hacking, and reinstall VS2K17, then get back to projects. If I come up with anything, I'll post an update.